# How to complete this c# code???asked in CTS

Tags: c#, oop

this question was asked in an interview.I couldn't solve this,it's incomplete.What must be replaced with question mark in "Human" class. please help me with it...

```
class  Dog()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog runs");
    }
}
class Cat()
{
    public void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cat runs");
    }
}
class  Human
{
    public void run(???????? x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Human runs");
        x.run();

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dog dog=new Dog();
        Cat cat=new Cat();
        Human human=new Human();
        human.run(cat);
        human.run(dog);
    }
}*
```

Comment: `class  Dog()` - syntax error. Is this actually the code they gave you?

Comment: It's an interview and you feel like the question is incomplete. Why not notify them of this, and explain *why* you think it is incomplete? Say what you **expected** to be there for the question to be complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you cannot change any other part of the program other than the `??????` then the only choice (after fixing the syntax errors in the other class definitions) is `dynamic`:

```
public void run(dynamic x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Human runs");
    x.run();
}
```

That's some weird code though. I hate questions like that which make no practical sense...

Comment: Well. You are right. But I can't imagine that he has to do something like that. Because thats just more than weird code...

Comment: @matthew is this class  Dog() right

Comment: @Rex No, the OP's clearly got typos in the original question: There cannot be the empty brackets after the class names `()`. I've just assumed that is a mistake and ignored them.

Answer (score 7):

If you are allowed to change the code: do something like that. 
If not, use the dynamic keyword (like it was mentioned in another answer). And just by the way: Your syntax is wrong. `class Dog() ...` is just wrong. Why putting `()` in there?

```
interface IPet
{
    void run();
}

class  Dog : IPet
{
    public void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog runs");
    }
}
class Cat : IPet
{
    public void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cat runs");
    }
}
class  Human
{
    public void run(IPet x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Human runs");
        x.run();

    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dog dog=new Dog();
        Cat cat=new Cat();
        Human human=new Human();
        human.run(cat);
        human.run(dog);
    }
}
```

Comment: They asked to replace the question mark. You added a completely new interface and made both `Dog` and `Cat` implement it. Not sure if that's what was expected. Either way, the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer. But using the dynamic keyword like already mentioned above... is just weird.

Comment: So. I am right, but mark the other answer as the right answer. Thats a bit confusing :).